# Criar coluna no R

Tags: r

Tenho uma coluna com 3 tipos de informações: numérica, percentual e carácter. Gostaria de criar duas novas colunas a partir dessa, um com apenas as informações em carácter ficando as demais células "NA" e outra coluna com apenas as informações numéricas ficando as informações carácter e as demais "NA" nesta nova coluna. 
Objetivo é criar duas novas colunas a partir da coluna Code. Uma com os números e outra com os códigos (factor).

`dput(head(estudo, 10)) structure(list(Potreiro = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1A", "6B", "7A", "7B"), class = "factor"), Code = structure(c(4L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 7L ), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "50%", "70%", "ac", "ad", "av", "cd", "de", "Dem"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Potreiro", "Code"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Brasil! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Seja mais claro por favor, dê exemplos de como já tentou resolver a questão e use as ferramentas de formatação para melhorar a legibilidade de pergunta.

Comment: Cada coluna de uma dataframe só tem **um tipo** de informação. Como está a dizer os números foram transformados em carácter e depois, quase certamente, em `factor`. Por favor edite a pergunta com a saída de `dput(df)` para nós vermos como isso está.

Comment: Exatamente Rui Barradas, estão todos como factor mas preciso usar alguns como número por isso quero criar mais colunas cada uma com um tipo de informação (número, factor...). Tentei ifelse(), mas deu erro: behaviour2$heigth <- ifelse(behaviour2$Code== ">1",  sep = "")
Error in ifelse(behaviour2$Code == ">1", sep = "") : 
  unused argument (sep = "")     e  também                      behaviour2$heigth <- ifelse(behaviour2$Code== ">1")
Error in ifelse(behaviour2$Code == ">1") : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default      Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: leia o [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) que o @MarcusNunes recomendou e coloque o resultado de `dput(head(behaviour2, 10))`. Tem muita gente querendo te ajudar, mas eles não conseguem adivinhar o seu problema, sua descrição não foi suficiente.

Comment: Objetivo é criar duas novas colunas a partir da coluna Code. Uma com os números e outra com os códigos (factor). dput(head(estudo, 10))
structure(list(Potreiro = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1A", "6B", "7A", "7B"), class = "factor"), 
    Code = structure(c(4L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 7L
    ), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "50%", "70%", "ac", "ad", 
    "av", "cd", "de", "Dem"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Potreiro", 
"Code"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame") Muito Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Bem estranho essa forma de guardar o banco de dados, mas de qualquer forma, segue código que faz o que tu precisa:

```
df <- structure(list(Potreiro = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1A", "6B", "7A", "7B"), class = "factor"), Code = structure(c(4L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 7L ), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "50%", "70%", "ac", "ad", "av", "cd", "de", "Dem"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Potreiro", "Code"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
df$Code <- as.character(df$Code)
df$numero <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", df$Code))
df$char <- ifelse(grepl("[[:alpha:]]", df$Code), df$Code, NA)
df$perc <- factor(grepl("%", df$Code), labels = c("Não", "Sim"))
```

Note que foi necessário utilizar expressão regular para primeiro buscar e retirar o `%`, pois só assim cria-se uma coluna numérica.

Em seguida, procurar se existia algum caracter na coluna para criar a coluna de caracter.

Como o `70` e `50` são percentuais, criei a couna `perc` que sinaliza se a coluna número é um Percentual.

Veja se era isso que tu precisava:

```
   Potreiro Code numero char perc
1        7A    5      5 <NA>  Não
2        7A    2      2 <NA>  Não
3        7A   ad     NA   ad  Não
4        7A    4      4 <NA>  Não
5        7A    3      3 <NA>  Não
6        7B    5      5 <NA>  Não
7        7A  70%     70 <NA>  Sim
8        7B  50%     50 <NA>  Sim
9        7A   ad     NA   ad  Não
10       7B   ac     NA   ac  Não
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library (tidyverse)
```

Uma possibilidade é utilizar a função `case_when()` combinada com `str_detect()`, empregando regex para filtrar o que você quer.

O detalhe é que quando a função `case_when()` encontra o padrão especificado, ela retorna o resultado. Quando não encontra, ela retorna justamente o `NA` que você está buscando.

Aproveitando o df criado pelo @Guilherme Parreira:

```
df <- structure(list(Potreiro = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1A", "6B", "7A", "7B"), class = "factor"), Code = structure(c(4L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 7L ), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "50%", "70%", "ac", "ad", "av", "cd", "de", "Dem"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Potreiro", "Code"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Usei as seguintes regex para criar as colunas:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(percent = case_when(str_detect(Code, "%") ~ Code),
         letra = case_when(str_detect(Code, "[a-z]") ~ Code),
         numero = case_when(!str_detect(Code, "[0-9]%|[a-z]") ~ Code))
```

Resultado:

```
Potreiro Code percent letra numero
1        7A    5    <NA>  <NA>      5
2        7A    2    <NA>  <NA>      2
3        7A   ad    <NA>    ad   <NA>
4        7A    4    <NA>  <NA>      4
5        7A    3    <NA>  <NA>      3
6        7B    5    <NA>  <NA>      5
7        7A  70%     70%  <NA>   <NA>
8        7B  50%     50%  <NA>   <NA>
9        7A   ad    <NA>    ad   <NA>
10       7B   ac    <NA>    ac   <NA>
```